# How can I invalidate cached field access grants for anonymous users?

Tags: 8, hooks, caching, event-subscribers

We have a Drupal 8 application that uses an event subscriber class to validate IP addresses against a table of white-listed addresses on kernel requests, and adds that value to a session variable. Basically, anonymous users with authenticated IPs can access privileged content on the site. I can use `hook_node_access` and `hook_block_access` to control access when appropriate, but `hook_entity_field_access` only fires once after rebuilding the caches, and not for each session, so field access seems more difficult to control this way. I've thought about injecting a service into my event subscriber and adding the necessary logic there for field access control, but I'm wondering if there's something easier that I'm missing about invalidating cache tags that would cause that hook to fire for each session.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use `hook_entity_field_access` and return an `AccessResult $result->addCacheContexts(['session', 'user.roles.anonymous'])`

Comment: Nice solution..